# Push an update for an app which is pending developer release in itunes connect

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store-connect

I have a question about itunes connect, if I submit an app to itunes connect but set it to pending developers release, will I be able to submit an update for that app without releasing my initial version?

In other words, can I update an app which is pending developers release?

Cheers Daan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your app in iTunes Connect, select Binary Details and then reject binary. This will reject your update that is pending developer release. Then you can submit a new version of your app.

Comment: I understand that, but my question is if I submit a initial version of my app (not a update) will i be able to submit an update for that app, even if I didn't release it yet. This way I can still release my initial version on the set date if my update gets rejected.

Comment: As long as you have one non-published version of your app (even if it is the initial version), adding a second version is not possible, as far as I know.

Comment: How long should we wait if we follow the suit? Shall the app to be reviewed all over again ?

Comment: You can update an app that's pending developer release without rejecting your version - http://stackoverflow.com/a/36775008/584774