# update an app which is pending developer release

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have an app which is in pending developer release (approved by Apple). The app was never released at all. Now I wanted to submit an update. Therefore I increased the `CFBundleVersion`, but he complained. So I increased the `CFBundleShortVersionString` too.

In iTunes Connect I can see under pre-releases my new submission. But in the versions view I see the old release. So how can I approve the update? It would be nice if I could manage the time of the release by myself. So that it stays in pending for developer release.

What are my options? Should I reject the binary? What version/build numbers should I take? Can I reuse the old ones?

Comment: I suppose you must reject binary (pending developer release) and continue with the new version. I suppose you must change the version number, because is a new one, even you can not release to production but approved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will *have to* reject the current build and remove it from **Versions** and then choose the new build you want to use.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: So I reject v. 1.0.0 (pending release) and submit the already uploaded v. 1.0.1 (update) for app store approval? So the version scheme I have chosen stays?

Comment: Well, if you reject the *Pending Developer Release* one then you just add the new build to that version (1.0.0) and upload.

Answer (score 45):

You don't have to reject the binary or cancel the release. You can instead:

1. Remove the app from all territories
2. Release the version. Its status will immediately change from "Pending Developer Release" to "Developer Removed From Sale".
3. Create a new version.

This way, if apple rejects the new binary or if you decide you want to release the old one after all, you can always release the old one.

Comment: I had to click the button "release this version" after removing all territories before it changed to "Developer Removed from Sale". Then I was able to setup a new version whilst keeping the old one.

Comment: @HugoScott-Slade Yes. I thought that's what I said ;)

Comment: Does this affect your launch momentum with sites that track new apps and Apple's New & Notable?

Comment: This is clever, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: So sneaky! Hack the App Store state engine!

Comment: This seems like it would also work as a scenario for providing a ready-to-go rollback build. Am I crazy?

Comment: @cobberboy This will remove the app from the App Store until you upload the new build?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can developer reject the current version and then you can upload a new binary.
2. In order to manage the time of the release simply check the "manually release this version" option in the "Version Release panel" and also set the "Availability date" in the "Pricing tab" in the future(like in 2016 may be).

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

**This might be helpful as a quick solution.**
[image]