# iTunes Connect: Can I upload a new build with an old version?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have an app which hasn't been released yet. Now I already uploaded a build where I incremented the version to 1.0.1. (`CFBundleShortVersionString`). The reason why I've done this is because he complained on submitting the new build to make it short.

Can I upload a new build with version 1.0.0?

**Edit:**

Longer version of the story:

1. Got the app approved by Apple, but it was always in pending developer release.
2. Found some bugs and corrected them. Therefore I uploaded a new build.
3. Application Loader complained on `CFBundleShortVersionString` so I incremented that.
4. [Then](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221372/update-an-app-which-is-pending-developers-release) I found out that I have to reject the app, which is what I've done now. I also removed the build from the *Versions* tab.
5. Now I want to release v. 1.0.0 but I already uploaded v. 1.0.1.

The app was never released.

**Solution:**

*Option 1:*

You simply send v. 1.0.1 in for review. But that is not what I wanted.

*Option 2:*

Make sure you rejected the binary and removed the build (from *Versions* tab). Increment the build number (in my case 1.0.3) and reset version to 1.0.0. Reupload binary and submit :-) PS: I think this is only possible if your app was never released. Now it looks strange in the pre-releases tab, because there is a newer version but with old build number.

Comment: iTunes into always required 1 point higher then current versions. If your 1.0 on app store then it's must be required 1.0.1 or higher. If you need more help please write whole scenario in details.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wanted to start with 1.0.0 for the user but it seems that isn't possible anymore. So I have to update the version number in iTunes under general app information. You can find the whole scenario in [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30221372/update-an-app-which-is-pending-developers-release). Currently I rejected v. 1.0.0 but I already uploaded v. 1.0.1. If you'd like I can summarize the whole story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ya it is possible, just change the `Buildno` = `previousBuildNo + 1` and delete the old `ipa` file from `iTunes connect` and add the `new build`. if you reject the `Pending Developer Release` in old one then you just add the new build to that version `(1.0.0)` and upload.

[image]

Comment: It seems that deleting old builds is not possible.

Comment: in xcode change the build number and add again in new build in ituens connect , but before delete the old ipa details, if your old version does not released you can do this

Comment: How can one delete the old ipa details? I can see my build under pre-releases. But there doesn't seem to be an option for delete.

Comment: in under under pre-releases we can change our build, wait I give some reference link

Comment: ref [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25699404/new-itunes-user-interface-unable-to-find-ready-to-upload-binary/25699845#25699845) or ref [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767777/how-to-remove-a-build-from-itunes-connect)

Comment: if your app under with in "waiting for review" we can change/delete/modify everything

Comment: The app was pending for developer release. Under *Versions* I already removed the v. 1.0.0. Now I can see my uploads in the pre-releases tab (with v. 1.0.1). Will I be able to upload v. 1.0.0 here?

Comment: sure you can do this, now you modify the build no is last number + 1 ,   and upload the new build , have a nice day bro , it s the simple thing don't get fear, do it if you are facing any problem I will support you,

Comment: if you are facing any problem on new build or if u need any assistance this is my mail id : karthik.sarl@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

In a comment below that I wrote afterwords lies the correct answer.

> I've read the edit you made to the question: you can submit version 1.0.1 for review. The version number shown in iTunes Connect will automatically change to match it (it will probably ask you for confirmation, if I remember correctly).

**Original answer**

Was the app already approved? If so, you probably can't. Also, how did you upload version 1.0.1? Directly on top of version 1.0.0 or by creating a new version (which also means version 1.0.0 is Ready for Sale)?

I believe the new iTunes will only check the build number (`CFBundleVersion`) of apps with version (`CFBundleShortVersionString`) greater or equal to the currently unreleased apps. So you can submit version 1.0.1 without creating a new version on top of version 1.0.0 but only if the latter was not released yet. The moment you release a version it will start checking for the version number as well.

E.g. you have v1.0.0 in a status other than 'Ready for Sale'. In this case you can upload and submit v1.0.1 without having to create a new version in iTunes Connect. Otherwise you won't be able to simply replace the build. You'd need to create a new version in iTunes Connect.

Comment: App was approved by Apple but was always in pending for developer release. I simply incremented the `CFBundleShortVersionString` because he complained on uploading using the Application Loader. So in my case I think the app is kind of released? But I don't quite get your last example.

Comment: So Application Loader let you upload version 1.0.1 even though your app was 'Ready for Sale' or 'Pending Developer Release'?

Comment: Yes, application loader allowed me to upload v. 1.0.1 despite it was in *Pending Developer Release*. It was required to increment the version otherwise I wasn't allowed to upload the binary.

Comment: I've read the edit you made to the question: you can submit version 1.0.1 for review. The version number shown in iTunes Connect will automatically change to match it (it will probably ask you for confirmation, if I remember correctly).