# Pending developer release questions

Tags: app-store

A few quick questions.

We have an application that is "pending developer release" on itunesconnect. the app was never released.

1. If I click "Release this version" - how long will it actually take until the app will appear on the appstore?

We managed to fix some minor UI issues and would like to upload a new build **before** releasing this version that is pending release.

2. Can we submit the new build we have that is better than the version that is pending release ?
3. What is the timeframe for approving the new build ? i mean, is it the same like the initial review ?
4. in general, how long does it takes until an update is approved ?

Thanks !

Comment: Regarding your second question, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/36775008/2012123. It is possible to "Release this version" and right after that upload a new version with the bug fixes. You are still able to release the old version "buggy"-version, if you are under time pressure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers.

1. It's could take up to 72 hours to make worldwide rollout
2. You can, but you must rejected this version first and then you must wait for a new review process.
3. It's similar to the initial review.
4. Time is variable and depend 100% for review team. In general its takes 1 week.

Answer (score 0):

It can take from a few minutes to almost a day for a newly released app to appear in various (localized) App stores around the world.  One trick to get a bogus approved update out of the way is to release the app in one tiny country (Luxembourg, et.al.) for one day, then remove it from sale in all countries until the next update is approved and ready for release.

In my experience, app updates have taken from less than two days to over a month to approve (or reject), averaging around one week or so.  See:  http://appreviewtimes.com/ios/distribution-chart